# Residue theorem background

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello can anyone help? I'm currently working on a paper about the residue theorem and I'm having trouble finding the historical background such as year founded, who modified it, year published, etc. Can anyone recommend any books or websites that I may use. Thanks!